# Looking for a logic check on this convergence conjecture

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Just asking for a logic check here.  I found a problem in an older edition of Strang's *Calculus*, and I thought I'd have a crack at it.  Is my solution even in the neighborhood of correct?  The paraphrased problem is stated thusly:

> If a sequence $a_1,\ a_2,\ a_3,...$ converges to zero, then we may put those elements in any order, and the new sequence will still converge to zero.

I figure that from the definition of limits, we can write the following $$\exists N : 0<N<n \implies |a_n|<\varepsilon $$

If we consider the set of all terms which are enumerated in $a_n$ (let's call that set $A$, and then define another sequence, $b$, such that the terms of $b$ must be drawn uniquely from $A$, then the above definition we can surmise that there are exactly $N$ members of $A$ which are greater than $\varepsilon$.  Once all $N$ said members have been enumerated in the order of $b$, then all other terms of $b$ must be smaller than any $\epsilon$, which implies that $b$ eventually begins to converge toward zero.

Comment: I don't understand your definition.  The usual definition of a sequence converging to $0$ is that $\forall \epsilon >0\;\exists N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $n>N\implies |a_n|<\epsilon$.  I think that, with that definition, you can get your logic to go through.

Comment: Whoops!  Wrote my definition backward; I'll correct it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Every converging sequence is Cauchy. Also if a sequence $a_n$ converges then a subsequence  $a_{k_n}$ also converges.

Comment: @Sentinel135 Okay, so that's super interesting, but my mathematical knowledge is not yet sophisticated enough to make sense of what it means for a sequence to be 'Cauchy'.  Mostly I'm just looking to see if my thinking as I've formulated it is valid.

Comment: Oh... Sorry for a sequence to be Cauchy, it means that "Given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an $N$ such that for $n,m>N$ we have $|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon$." Basically this is a more rigorous condition of convergence that no longer requires the condition of knowing what a sequence converges to.

Comment: As for your concept, it's iffy. mainly because we don't know where those are in the new sequence $b_n$.  Also Not all members of $a_n$ where $n \leq N$ are necessarily outside of the bounded region either. we just know that some of them are. Example Let $A :=\{a_n= 1/n\: \mathrm {if} \:n=2k,\: \exists k\in \mathbb Z,\:\mathbb{or}\: a_n=0 \: \mathrm{otherwise}\}$ this set converges to $0$ and for every odd $n$ $a_n=0$.

Comment: @Sentinel135 I think I understand your reservations about $a_n$ being non-monotonic, but since we're talking about infinite sequences here, does the order of $b$ actually matter when $N$ is finite?

Comment: That's why I said it's iffy... The concept works but is hard to prove as we don't know where in the new sequence the old numbers are. So we can't exactly say, "Hey, I found a one of the bad $b_n$'s! This should be the last one so the rest are good right?"

It would be literally like hunting for a group of bad needles in a giant pile of "good" needles in a factory that's still making more needles. I guess what I am saying is that your idea could work with specific cases but you will have a hard time doing this generally.